# Scaling 1D ArrayPlot divide by zero error

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

I am trying to overlay an ArrayPlot onto a WaveletScalogram, using the helpful answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51842/combining-arrayplot-and-plot); however, my ArrayPlot is one-dimensional.

My code:

```
Show[{
  WaveletScalogram[trainWaveData["A1 HbO"], Ticks -> Full, PlotLabel -> "A1 HbO"],
  ArrayPlot[{trainLabel}, DataRange -> {{0, 100}, {-1, 0}}]
}]
```

`trainLabel` looks like `{1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, ...}`.

I get the following error:

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
```

This happens for any `DataRange` I give. I'm not sure what to do. Can I put in a dummy row for it to fill, or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: To help you with debugging, in the absence of sample data: do the two plots work separately?

Comment: This `ArrayPlot[{RandomChoice[{0., 1.}, 200]}, DataRange -> {{0, 100}, {-1, 0}}]` works fine so it must be the definition of your `trainWaveData` function. Without knowing how that was defined there's little that can be done to help you